# How to make nodeJS code public

Tags: node.js, file-upload

How I could upload my nodeJS code on server to make it public. What's the difference between uploading a normal html file and html file with a nodeJS code?

Comment: Are you trying to share your node.js code or are you trying to make your web server accessible to the public, but not your node.js code?  My answer below assumed you were trying to "make nodeJS code public" because that's what your title says, but now I'm not sure if that's what you really meant.

Answer (score 2):

Node.js is a server side scripting, javascript framework which runs on top of Chromes V8 engine. Now, what makes it different is that the application developed using node can be seen as a server responding to your request. While scripting using node.js we are creating a http server which keeps on responding to your request. In other words, when you are running a nodejs application you are running an instance of a http server. Its quite different from the scenario where you install a separate web server like apache or nginx with appropriate language compiler packages and then deploying your code in the web root of it to be served by it.

## You just have to install node.js on your server and run your app using it.

Now if any thing goes wrong due to high load or some unhandled exception in the script not only the application crashes, in a way your instance of web server itself is crashing. So you need to keep monitoring your application and may need to re-start it if any thing goes wrong. There can also be cases when your host system/server itself is rebooting.

There should be something which can respawn the node process when needed. This can be done by using forever, nodemon or crontab until and unless your host system itself is not getting restarted. In such scenarios we need something more effective.

We can take care of such cases, in linux systems by following these two steps:
1. Set your node application to start with system service managers or daemons.
2. Use some tools which watches the linux daemon and does it for you.

Step 1: Using Process manager (Upstart)
We can use the upstart to make the node process to be managed by daemons or say run in background. You will not need to keep the terminal open always. Also you will be able to get easily configurable start/restart/stop scripts. Various linux flavours like RHEL, Ubuntu, CentOS and Fedora have it bundled with it.

Step 2: Using Monit (The watcher)
We can use monit as its name suggests, to monitor the daemon process, filesystems, directories, localhost and also the various process characteristics like memory and CPU cycles associated with a process.
So it can be used to automate the actions to be taken, for a wide range of scenarios which are associated with not only an application crash but also like high resource utilization, security breach and file changes.
Using it we can configure tests that will be evaluated at certain intervals.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to publicly share any set of code is to open a free GitHub account and put your code on GitHub.  If you want to look at a sample project on GitHub, you can look at the actual [node.js source code here](https://github.com/joyent/node).

On GitHub you create a project and can then organize the various files related to that project in whatever way seems best to you.  The HTML files would likely go in a different place (e.g. directory) than the node.js Javascript files.

Once you are using GitHub, you can also use it for your source control system (versioning, branches, tags, etc...).

---

If what you actually meant by "How to make nodeJS code public" is how to make your node.js server accessible to the public so that the web pages it serves can be accessed from the general internet, then that is a completely different question.  In that case, you need to find a computer/host that is accessible to the internet and you need to install your node.js code on that server.  This is commonly done through a hosting arrangement with services such as Amazon Web Services, Rackspace, Joyent (the makers of node.js), Nodejitsu, and thousands of others, etc...  You will generally want to look for a hosting provider that has specific support for node.js so you are sure that it supports all the relevant tools, long running server processes, webSockets, etc...